# Как работать с ObjectAnimator?

Tags: kotlin, objectanimator

Всем привет! Как сделать прыжок вверх таким же плавным, как и вниз? Котлин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```
binding.jump.setOnClickListener {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(binding.hero,View.TRANSLATION_Y,-400F,0F).apply {
        duration=1300
    }.start()
    //--------------------------
    heroAnimation.stop()
    //---------------------------
    Handler().postDelayed({heroAnimation.start()},1100)
}
```